# How to use spring internalResourceviewresolver muliple times in spring mvc xml file

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

How to use spring `InternalResourceViewResolver` multiple times in spring mvc xml file?

I defined in `WEB-INF` 4  folders, containing jsps, like admin, user, developer, tester but in spring mvc xml file using single `InternalResourceViewResolver` and single folder.

Example

```
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix"><value>/WEB-INF/admin/</value></property>
    <property name="suffix"><value>.jsp</value></property>
</bean>
```

Comment: You cannot. The `InternalResourceViewResolver` always returns a view regardless of it exists or not. Define a single one and return `admin/viewname` from your controller instead.

Comment: Thanks Deinum. How to call multiple module folders inside jsp file. ex admin have 4 jsp files, user have 5 jsp file ...... please tell me any another way . Thanks,

Comment: There isn't and it would be strange for the same JSP to have multiple controllers. So it simply isn't possible (at least not without modifying the `InternalResourceViewResolver` yourself also imho it would be a bad idea to do this...

Answer (score 2):

**You cannot use InternalResourcerViewResolver multiple times in Spring xml.**

Instead put all your jsp files into views folder(any folder), and from the controller, call which page you want to go.

```
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix"><value>/WEB-INF/views/</value></property>
    <property name="suffix"><value>.jsp</value></property>
</bean>
```

The return ModelAndView or return will come to spring xml with "jsp file name" it will identify according to your property in the xml and it will go to appropriate jsp page.

Comment: Thanks vignesh, but i separated jsp pages in different folders. like admin, user, developer folders,  jsp pages  how to create viewresolvers separately in spring mvc xml file.   Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can have a try like this:

`<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>`